# Why Do Invalid Characters Get Into MarkLogic Database?

Tags: marklogic

I have discovered that it is possible to insert invalid XML characters into a MarkLogic database. This only becomes apparent if I happen to extract, xdmp:quote then later xdmp:unquote an XML document, whereupon I get a message such as "Invalid character entity '14'".

The character got into the database via an XQuery-generated HTML form submission. I think the user pasted text in from Excel, which includes such hidden nasties.

Clearly I am going to need to check what is being input in future, but surely this is abug that should be fixed. If the characters are illegal, why isnt MarkLogic stripping them out when saving data to the database?

Neil.

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic uses a parsed representation for XML both in memory and when persisting an XML document.  Invalid characters would cause parse failures, preventing MarkLogic from storing a document as XML.

However, MarkLogic can store an invalid serialization of XML as a text or binary document.  The bytes may be invalid for XML, but they aren't invalid for text or binary.

Is it possible that the HTML form submission submits the documents as text or binary instead of as XML?  What does `xdmp:node-kind()` report about the form submission and about the document when retrieved with `fn:doc()`?

Hoping that helps with the investigation,

Comment: NO. The data IS stored as XML, inserted into a document using xdmp:node-insert-child(), so there is no doubt in my mind that the illegal characters are stored in the database within XML data.

Note that as I said above, it only becomes apparent when using xdmp:quote to conver to a string, which now contains &#14;, then trying to convert back to XML using xdmp:unquote() I get the error.

Comment: I can prove what I am saying with some examples.

First, this example shows the effect in memory. There is an error qhen unquoting:

let $XML := <TEST>Here is invalid character 14: {fn:codepoints-to-string((14))}</TEST>
let $Quoted := xdmp:quote($XML)
let $Unquoted := xdmp:unquote($Quoted)
return
  $Unquoted

Comment: Second, this proves the invalid character is stored in the database:


let $Doc := <TEST>Here is invalid character 14: {fn:codepoints-to-string((14))}</TEST>
return
  xdmp:document-insert("/Test.xml", $Doc)
  
;

let $Quoted := xdmp:quote(/TEST)
let $Unquoted := xdmp:unquote($Quoted)
return
  $Unquoted

Comment: I stand corrected. I'm able to reproduce with the sample code that you posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449020/why-is-marklogic-definitely-storing-invalid-characters-in-xml-documents .  Please file a support ticket with that reproduction case. A support ticket provides focus for a fix.